# how to solve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

When i run my project, this exception appears

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ressourceDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory ma.controle.gestion.dao.RessourceDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's my configuration files:

applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

```
<bean id="structure" class="ma.controle.gestion.model.Structure"/>
<bean id="ressource" class="ma.controle.gestion.model.Ressource"/>

<bean id="ressourceDao"     class="ma.controle.gestion.dao.RessourceDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="structureDao"     class="ma.controle.gestion.dao.StructureDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="structureService" class="ma.controle.gestion.service.StructureServiceImpl">
    <property name="structureDao" ref="structureDao"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="ressourceService" class="ma.controle.gestion.service.RessourceService">
    <property name="ressourceDao" ref="ressourceDao"></property>        
</bean> 

   <!--Hibernate-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/controlegestion?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>ma.controle.gestion.model.Ressource</value>
            <value>ma.controle.gestion.model.Affectation</value>
            <value>ma.controle.gestion.model.Structure</value>
            <value>ma.controle.gestion.model.Activite</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

pom.xml

```
 <properties>
    <cp30.version>0.9.1.2</cp30.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.25</mysql.version>
    <jpa.version>1.0.0.Final</jpa.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <commons-codec.version>1.9</commons-codec.version>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring MVC-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--C3P0 Connection Pooling-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${cp30.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--MySQL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--APACHE COMMONS CODEC-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--LOG4J-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/barcelona</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8100</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                        <targetPath>sources</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>distribute</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-layout</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>src/assemble/layout.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <finalName>${project.name}-layout-${project.version}</finalName>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-theme</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>src/assemble/theme.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <finalName>${project.name}-theme-${project.version}</finalName>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here is my classe RessourceDaoImpl

```
package ma.controle.gestion.dao;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ma.controle.gestion.model.Ressource;

@Repository
public class RessourceDaoImpl implements IRessourceDao{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



@Override
public void addRessource(Ressource ressource) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(ressource);

}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}


}
```

I lost a lot of time to find the error but i cant do it, i need help pleaaaase

Comment: You're using spring version 4.1.5 as defined in your maven pom, why are you using  XSDs from version 3.0?  Remove the versions from the definitions in the config files e.g. change `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd` to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` so that spring picks automatically the right xsds for you. Do that for the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, i changed XSDs to 
        spring-beans.xsd
        spring-context.xsd
        spring-tx.xsd
but the problem remains

Comment: Have you placed your packages using this `<context:component-scan base package="your package" />` in the config file? Otherwise with `@Autowired` spring won't be able to find the classes you are are calling because you didn't define where they should be found. So if you don't have this, you have to add it to your config each for any of the packages that you are using. `context` is the namespace for `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`  BTW that first comment was besides the point and was just a tip ;).

Comment: I already have this line in my code I lost 5 days during my internship for this error :( :(